# Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file

Tags: png

I cannot open pictures with type PNG, and if i open a picture, it shows me this message (Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file)
How can i solve this problem please ?

Comment: I think the PNG file itself is corrupted, or is different filetype renamed to .png

Answer (score 3):

You may have a corrupt PNG library.  Try reinstalling it.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpng*-dev
```

Comment: Does not fix for me!